# Prove an operator is positive

Tags: functional-analysis

Define $L[\psi](x):=\int_{-1}^1\frac{\sin c(x-y)}{\pi(x-y)}\psi(y)dy,\,\forall \psi\in L^2(-1,1).$

Then $L\in\mathfrak{C}(L^2(-1,1))$, where $\mathfrak{C}(L^2(-1,1))$ means the space consisting of compact operators from $L^2(-1,1)$ to itself.

Now I wonder how to prove that $L$ is a positive operator, i.e. $\langle Lu,u\rangle\gt0\,,\forall u\in L^2(-1,1).$

Can someone offer me a hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
  L\psi &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sin(c(x-y))}{x-y}\psi(y)dy \\
  &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-c}^{c}e^{is(x-y)}ds\psi(y)dy \\
  &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-c}^{c}\int_{-1}^{1} \psi(y)e^{-isy}dy e^{isx}ds
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
   \langle L\psi,\psi \rangle & =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-c}^{c}\int_{-1}^{1}\psi(y)e^{-isy}dy\;\overline{\int_{-1}^{1}\psi(x)e^{-isx}dx} ds \\
 & = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-c}^{c}\left|\int_{-1}^{1}\psi(y)e^{-isy}dy\right|^2ds \ge 0.
\end{align}
If $\langle L\psi,\psi \rangle = 0$, then $\int_{-1}^{1}\psi(y)e^{-isy}dy = 0$ for all $s\in[-c,c]$ which implies the same for all $s$ because the function is holomorphic in $s$ for a $s$. Hence $\psi=0$ a.e. in this case. So $L > 0$.

Comment: A very clear proof. Thanks!